# Azure redis cache and Django setup

Tags: django, redis, digital-ocean, azure-redis-cache

Am using `django-redis` in Django to add Azure redis cache, but I am getting issues with the connection, I added the keys password and the hostname and the port but no luck , I get this error :

```
django_redis.exceptions.ConnectionInterrupted: Redis ConnectionError: Error while reading from myhostname.net:6380 : (104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

I tried reading existing answers but no luck.

This is what I have in my Django `settings.py` :

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": os.getenv('REDIS_URL'),
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            'SSL': True,
            "PASSWORD": os.getenv('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        }
    }
}
```

Where `REDIS_URL` is like this :

```
REDIS_URL=rediss://myhostname.net:6380
```

and as well as `REDIS_PASSWORD` the password provided.

What could I be missing, am testing this on Digitalocean, I have an SSL activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here I was not getting the connection error by using the Location tag in the following format

```
"LOCATION":'rediss://:<Your password>@<name of the redis in azure>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0'
```

The complete code:

```
CACHES = {
    'default':{
                'BACKEND':'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
                "LOCATION":'rediss://:<Your password>@<name of the redis in azure>.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/0',
                'OPTION':{
                            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
                            'PASSWORD':'<Your password>',
                            'SSL': True
                        }
            }
}
```

After starting the Django app, output:

[image]